# MySQL Event Schedule Datediff

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datediff, mysql-event

**When i try to execute this SQL, i got an error, bellow :**

**SQL Query :**

```
CREATE EVENT fine
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
DO
if datediff(CURRENT_DATE,transactions.return_date) > 0
UPDATE transactions SET fine = fine + 1000
end if
```

> ERROR : #1054 - Unknown column 'return_date' in 'field list'

**and here my transactions table columns :**

- id
- user_id
- book_id
- borrow_date
- return_date
- fine

**Please anyone help me, much thanks!!**

Comment: You have to select return_date and and if must have a then and there should ONLY be an update statement anyway. Write a working update statement then put it into an event.

Comment: can you give me some example sir?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: Not if, WHERE..

Comment: ohh its DONE by : CREATE EVENT fine ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO UPDATE transactions SET fine = IF(datediff(CURRENT_DATE,return_date) > 0, fine + 1000,fine+0)

THANK YOU @P.Salmon